# Redirect on Bad Authentication ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpmodule, adfs2.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC site running in a Framework 4.0 app pool. I need to now put Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) in front of it for authentication against a remote AD store. If authentication fails, I would like to redirect to my own custom page. What is the right way to do this? Since ADFS is implemented in an HTTP Module, should I make my own "reject module" and put it before or after the ADFS one?

Comment: did  you get final solution with **HTTP module** ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of authentication are you using? IF FBA, just modify the ADFS FormsSignIn.aspx to redirect to your custom page on failure.